# React/Webpack: ESLint warns for no longer existing files

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

I have a problem that the Javascript console for my React project shows ESLint warnings for files that no longer exist. For example, it shows the following:

```
[HMR] bundle 'preview' has 1 warnings

undefined undefined
[eslint]
  src/components/Header.jsx
Line 10:7:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
```

Except the file "src/components/Header.jsx" doesn't exist anymore; I moved it to src/components/header/Header.jsx (and also already added the alt prop).

I tried "npm run build" to no effect. How can I re-build this to make the incorrect warnings disappear?

Comment: @LalitTyagi Maybe I don't understand your question. I am only importing it from one place (in "src/pages/Landing.jsx": import { Header } from '../components/header/Header';)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the problem go away by re-initializing Storybook using `npx storybook init; npm run storybook`. Not sure what was the cause though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, server restart fix it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).